# Flutter android app crash in release mode

Tags: android, flutter

My Flutter android app is crashing in Release mode only. Here the error I see in Firebase analytics.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Illegal class access: 'g.j.a.Q' attempting to access 'n.a.t' (declaration of 'g.j.a.Q' appears in /data/app/~~JF7EOTBYKSHN2CavjjfbSw==/com.RandstadRecruiter-dOeFJGtqYrQtrKeem7SsnQ==/base.apk)
       at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.a(SingleProcessDataStore.java:28)
       at androidx.datastore.preferences.core.PreferenceDataStore.updateData(PreferenceDataStore.java:8)
       at androidx.datastore.preferences.core.PreferencesKt.edit(Preferences.kt:6)
       at com.google.firebase.sessions.settings.SettingsCache.updateConfigValue(SettingsCache.java:62)
       at com.google.firebase.sessions.settings.SettingsCache.updateSettingsEnabled(SettingsCache.java:2)
       at com.google.firebase.sessions.settings.RemoteSettings$updateSettings$2$1.invokeSuspend(RemoteSettings.java:211)
       at com.google.firebase.sessions.settings.RemoteSettings$updateSettings$2$1.invoke(RemoteSettings.java:8)
       at com.google.firebase.sessions.settings.RemoteSettings$updateSettings$2$1.invoke(RemoteSettings.java:4)
       at com.google.firebase.sessions.settings.RemoteSettingsFetcher$doConfigFetch$2.invokeSuspend(:162)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(BaseContinuationImpl.java:2)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.java:86)
```

In my gradle file, I am targeting
minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 33

Here is the output from the doctor command

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.9, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.7.9 on channel stable at /Applications/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 62bd79521d (5 months ago), 2023-03-30 10:59:36 -0700
    • Engine revision ec975089ac
    • Dart version 2.19.6
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/premchandbudhu/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.70.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64 • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are availabl
```

Comment: All the short 1-letter names like g.j.a.Q look like obfuscated classnames.  You probably need to find out how you upload those to Firebase so that it can help you figure out where the error really is.